# Difference between T(FullyClassifiedClassName) and #{Bean} when passed as Expression in SpEL

Tags: spring-el

I am learning about SpEL and I was facing a problem with one concept of Spring SpEL, as I was not able to distinguish between T(className) and #{beanName} when passing as an expression in @Value()

```
@Value("T(fullyClassifiedClassName)")
```

```
@Value("#{beanName}")// name of bean which is present in our IOC Container
```

also correct me if I am wrong, but till now I have understood that I can use StandardEvalutionContext to specify the object to evaluate the expression against.

Answer (score 1):

The `T` operator returns the class object; a bean is an instance of a class.